# What object3D properties are required to make rayCaster.intersectObjects() work?

Tags: webgl, raycasting, three.js

FYI, I am trying to do something almost identical to the following:
[Merging geometry/mesh without losing benefits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81570/merging-geometry-mesh-without-losing-benefits?newreg=78c48ec3facd4dc9852b4e42b66e9ad0)

I essentially have a list of Three.object3D's. These objects are "merged" together into a single `BufferGeometry` (so that I can draw thousands of these objects with a single draw call).

After merging these objects I still do have references to all of the original objects (via a class which simply "has a" object3D object reference).

*** Question ***

I am calling `raycaster.intersectObjects(myObjects)` on this list of original Object3D's. I'm wondering what properties are required for this `intersectObjects` method to work? In other words, the ray caster must be checking against each objects position and geometry. What properties (position, geometry?) are required and where do these properties exist (within the Object3D reference)?

Whew. I hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are dependent on the override of the class that inherits from object which is currently being used. You can see what properties are required by looking at the overridden method that will have the format of `THREE.ClassName.prototype.raycast`. See below for a bit of insight into whats actually going on when you use the raycaster.

### [Raycaster.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js)

```
var intersectObject = function ( object, raycaster, intersects, recursive ) {

    object.raycast( raycaster, intersects ); //The important bit

    if ( recursive === true ) {

        var children = object.children;

        for ( var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
            intersectObject( children[ i ], raycaster, intersects, true );
        }
    }
};
```

### [Object3D.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js)

```
raycast: function () {},
```

The Raycaster doesn't perform the collision logic its self. The Object has a method called `raycast` that does that for it. For the Object3D class that method perform no logic. However if you go look at [mesh](http://Mesh.js) override that's a hell of a method.

```
THREE.Mesh.prototype.raycast = ( function () {

    var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    var ray = new THREE.Ray();
    var sphere = new THREE.Sphere();

    var vA = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vB = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vC = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function ( raycaster, intersects ) {

        var geometry = this.geometry;

        // Checking boundingSphere distance to ray

        if ( geometry.boundingSphere === null ) geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

        sphere.copy( geometry.boundingSphere );
        sphere.applyMatrix4( this.matrixWorld );

        if ( raycaster.ray.isIntersectionSphere( sphere ) === false ) {

            return;

        }

        // Check boundingBox before continuing

        inverseMatrix.getInverse( this.matrixWorld );
        ray.copy( raycaster.ray ).applyMatrix4( inverseMatrix );

        if ( geometry.boundingBox !== null ) {

            if ( ray.isIntersectionBox( geometry.boundingBox ) === false )  {

                return;

            }

        }

        if ( geometry instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry ) {

            var material = this.material;

            if ( material === undefined ) return;

            var attributes = geometry.attributes;

            var a, b, c;
            var precision = raycaster.precision;

            if ( attributes.index !== undefined ) {

                var indices = attributes.index.array;
                var positions = attributes.position.array;
                var offsets = geometry.offsets;

                if ( offsets.length === 0 ) {

                    offsets = [ { start: 0, count: indices.length, index: 0 } ];

                }

                for ( var oi = 0, ol = offsets.length; oi < ol; ++oi ) {

                    var start = offsets[ oi ].start;
                    var count = offsets[ oi ].count;
                    var index = offsets[ oi ].index;

                    for ( var i = start, il = start + count; i < il; i += 3 ) {

                        a = index + indices[ i ];
                        b = index + indices[ i + 1 ];
                        c = index + indices[ i + 2 ];

                        vA.set(
                            positions[ a * 3 ],
                            positions[ a * 3 + 1 ],
                            positions[ a * 3 + 2 ]
                        );
                        vB.set(
                            positions[ b * 3 ],
                            positions[ b * 3 + 1 ],
                            positions[ b * 3 + 2 ]
                        );
                        vC.set(
                            positions[ c * 3 ],
                            positions[ c * 3 + 1 ],
                            positions[ c * 3 + 2 ]
                        );


                        if ( material.side === THREE.BackSide ) {

                            var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( vC, vB, vA, true );

                        } else {

                            var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( vA, vB, vC, material.side !== THREE.DoubleSide );

                        }

                        if ( intersectionPoint === null ) continue;

                        intersectionPoint.applyMatrix4( this.matrixWorld );

                        var distance = raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( intersectionPoint );

                        if ( distance < precision || distance < raycaster.near || distance > raycaster.far ) continue;

                        intersects.push( {

                            distance: distance,
                            point: intersectionPoint,
                            indices: [ a, b, c ],
                            face: null,
                            faceIndex: null,
                            object: this

                        } );

                    }

                }

            } else {

                var positions = attributes.position.array;

                for ( var i = 0, j = 0, il = positions.length; i < il; i += 3, j += 9 ) {

                    a = i;
                    b = i + 1;
                    c = i + 2;

                    vA.set(
                        positions[ j ],
                        positions[ j + 1 ],
                        positions[ j + 2 ]
                    );
                    vB.set(
                        positions[ j + 3 ],
                        positions[ j + 4 ],
                        positions[ j + 5 ]
                    );
                    vC.set(
                        positions[ j + 6 ],
                        positions[ j + 7 ],
                        positions[ j + 8 ]
                    );


                    if ( material.side === THREE.BackSide ) {

                        var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( vC, vB, vA, true );

                    } else {

                        var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( vA, vB, vC, material.side !== THREE.DoubleSide );

                    }

                    if ( intersectionPoint === null ) continue;

                    intersectionPoint.applyMatrix4( this.matrixWorld );

                    var distance = raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( intersectionPoint );

                    if ( distance < precision || distance < raycaster.near || distance > raycaster.far ) continue;

                    intersects.push( {

                        distance: distance,
                        point: intersectionPoint,
                        indices: [ a, b, c ],
                        face: null,
                        faceIndex: null,
                        object: this

                    } );

                }

            }

        } else if ( geometry instanceof THREE.Geometry ) {

            var isFaceMaterial = this.material instanceof THREE.MeshFaceMaterial;
            var objectMaterials = isFaceMaterial === true ? this.material.materials : null;

            var a, b, c, d;
            var precision = raycaster.precision;

            var vertices = geometry.vertices;

            for ( var f = 0, fl = geometry.faces.length; f < fl; f ++ ) {

                var face = geometry.faces[ f ];

                var material = isFaceMaterial === true ? objectMaterials[ face.materialIndex ] : this.material;

                if ( material === undefined ) continue;

                a = vertices[ face.a ];
                b = vertices[ face.b ];
                c = vertices[ face.c ];

                if ( material.morphTargets === true ) {

                    var morphTargets = geometry.morphTargets;
                    var morphInfluences = this.morphTargetInfluences;

                    vA.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                    vB.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                    vC.set( 0, 0, 0 );

                    for ( var t = 0, tl = morphTargets.length; t < tl; t ++ ) {

                        var influence = morphInfluences[ t ];

                        if ( influence === 0 ) continue;

                        var targets = morphTargets[ t ].vertices;

                        vA.x += ( targets[ face.a ].x - a.x ) * influence;
                        vA.y += ( targets[ face.a ].y - a.y ) * influence;
                        vA.z += ( targets[ face.a ].z - a.z ) * influence;

                        vB.x += ( targets[ face.b ].x - b.x ) * influence;
                        vB.y += ( targets[ face.b ].y - b.y ) * influence;
                        vB.z += ( targets[ face.b ].z - b.z ) * influence;

                        vC.x += ( targets[ face.c ].x - c.x ) * influence;
                        vC.y += ( targets[ face.c ].y - c.y ) * influence;
                        vC.z += ( targets[ face.c ].z - c.z ) * influence;

                    }

                    vA.add( a );
                    vB.add( b );
                    vC.add( c );

                    a = vA;
                    b = vB;
                    c = vC;

                }

                if ( material.side === THREE.BackSide ) {

                    var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( c, b, a, true );

                } else {

                    var intersectionPoint = ray.intersectTriangle( a, b, c, material.side !== THREE.DoubleSide );

                }

                if ( intersectionPoint === null ) continue;

                intersectionPoint.applyMatrix4( this.matrixWorld );

                var distance = raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( intersectionPoint );

                if ( distance < precision || distance < raycaster.near || distance > raycaster.far ) continue;

                intersects.push( {

                    distance: distance,
                    point: intersectionPoint,
                    face: face,
                    faceIndex: f,
                    object: this

                } );

            }

        }

    };

}() );
```

Comment: Thanks for you very informative answer. So to summarize, looks like for non-buffer-geometry objects the only property that is pretty much used for ray-collision are the vertices. Correct?

Comment: I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I am calling intersectObjects on my list of mesh objects. These objects SHOULD be spread out all over the scene. However, the only object that gets intersected is the FIRST object only. All other objects are not being intersected. What could be the issue? Are my vertices for the other objects not correct?

Comment: I think i got it.... I just had to update my other mesh object vertices so that they reflect their location in world space!

Answer (score 0):

As posted [on threejs.org forums](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/object-3d-with-rayscaster/13934):

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( group.children);
```

Try it like so:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( group.children, true );
```

The second parameter indicates you want to test all descendants of group.children.